# Is possible sending emails without knowing the password?

Tags: email, joomla, hosting

My customer purchased hosting and email accounts (info@mycompany.com) at hostgator. The new project that I have to upload to his hostgator is sending emails from info@mycompany.com.

The question: can send those emails without knowing the password since he doesn't want to tell me the password?

He argues that there is currently a hosted project which is sending emails without knowing the password. I could not believe that, so I have checked the current project's config file and found this:

```
public $display_offline_message = '1';
public $offline_image = '';
public $sitename = ' My Company';
public $editor = 'tinymce';
public $captcha = 'recaptcha';
public $list_limit = '20';
public $access = '1';
public $debug = '0';
public $debug_lang = '0';
public $dbtype = 'mysql';
public $host = 'localhost';
public $user = 'mycompany_joomla';
public $password = 'N+4(fadafsfa';
public $db = 'mycompany_joomla';
public $dbprefix = 'h3hmb_';
public $live_site = '';
public $secret = 'fasdfadfsf';
public $gzip = '0';
public $error_reporting = 'default';
public $helpurl = 'http://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help{major}{minor}:{keyref}';
public $ftp_host = '127.0.0.1';
public $ftp_port = '21';
public $ftp_user = 'admin';
public $ftp_pass = '*****';
public $ftp_root = '';
public $ftp_enable = '0';
public $offset = 'Europe/Madrid';
public $mailer = 'mail';
public $mailfrom = 'contacto@mycompany.com';
public $fromname = 'My Company';
public $sendmail = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
public $smtpauth = '0';
public $smtpuser = '';
public $smtppass = '';  <<<<< I expected the password here
public $smtphost = 'localhost';
public $smtpsecure = 'none';
public $smtpport = '25';
public $caching = '0';
public $cache_handler = 'file';
public $cachetime = '15';
public $MetaDesc = '';
```

So is it true the current project doesn't know the password? Or if the password maybe written in another file?

Answer (score 2):

In the `configuration.php` you show, your main parameter for mail sending is :

```
public $mailer = 'mail';
```

i.e. it uses PHP [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function. Then in this case, credentials are not required for sending mails. Only :

```
public $mailfrom = 'contacto@mycompany.com';
public $fromname = 'My Company';
```

are useful.

The following parameters are mandatory only if you chose `smtp` :

```
public $smtpauth = '0';
public $smtpuser = '';
public $smtppass = ''; 
public $smtphost = 'localhost';
public $smtpsecure = 'none';
public $smtpport = '25';
```

More information in ["5.5 “Mail Settings” Group" of Joomla Doc](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Global_configuration)

Comment: Another similar answer for the same question and author : http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13661/is-possible-sending-emails-without-knowing-the-password